# What is the best approach to do boolean operations with multi meshes in Sverchok?

Tags: sverchok

I need to do boolean operations with multiple meshes, i found this solution as you can see in the image and in the script attached, but i think there are other possibilities; Probably with a script should be the best efficient solution ( with a `script_lite node` i mean), but maybe my `nodetree` could be also improved.

note few points:

- `list decompose node` became a bit oddy if you have to handle many meshes.
- i don't want to use metaballs.
- i want to do boolean union and subtraction.
- in the example i left the subdivision level at minimum for obviuos reasons.

Thank you for the attention.

Walter
@kalwalt

[image: multi boolean icosphere]
[ico_boolean script](https://github.com/kalwalt/sverchok_nodes_collection/blob/master/json/multi_icosphere_csg.json)

Comment: Due to new changes/improvements to  the CSG boolean this Nodetree can be simplified a lot. No needs anymore of the list decompose nodes and Csg chained boolean nodes. The Csg Boolean MK2 node now accept nested lists of meshes so simplifing a lot the node tree. For info about the node go to the pull request thread: https://github.com/nortikin/sverchok/pull/1575: